# Mongoose Typescript 2 Schema that have a field that use each other schemas

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I am trying to declare 2 schemas, using mongoose and typescript, that both have a field that their type is the other schema, like this:

```
const Schema1: Schema = new Schema({
    fieldA: Number,
    fieldB: Schema2

};

const Schema2: Schema = new Schema({
    fieldA : Number,
    fieldB : Schema1

};
```

The problem is that i get an error, because the Schema2, on the fieldB of Schema1 is being used before being assigned.

I already tried to declared it before like:

```
var Schema2: Schema = new Schema();
```

But then, when adding values to the database, Schema2 is just an empty schema with no fields.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like a circular relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create subdocuments like this. According to [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html#altsyntax), you can create an array of subdocuments and single subdocuments. And they always maintain the parent-child relationship.
In your case, if you want to use subdocuments, you must declare it first. So in *schema1*, you've declared *schema2* as a subdocument (child), but it got referenced below. The structure is

```
|--mongoose-schema
|--- children subdocument
|---- parent schema
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can add a field to the schema after you define it, like this:

```
Schema1.add({ fieldB: Schema2 });
```